# What's the difference between TaxAct and TurboTax?

Tags: united-states, small-business, taxes, limited-liability-company

I've always used TurboTax, but found an edition of TaxAct that will do state, federal plus schedule c for about 33 percent of the price of the Turbotax edition? Does TaxAct not do some important things that TurboTax does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer TaxAct. I find it simpler to use and more helpful in helping answer the questionnaire. I have a fairly complex tax return and it handles it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I typed my information into both last year, and while they were not exactly the same, they were within $10 of each other.

For my simple 2009 taxes they were not different in any meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My taxes are fairly complicated ... two states, domestic partnership in California, a single member LLC and schedule C. I'm guessing I should stick with the more expensive Turbotax.

Comment: @Final Draft - I would vote an accountant or registered agent for complicated taxes.  At least the first couple of times.  Do yourself a favor and do your own taxes with the software but don't file.  Then visit a pro to get a sense of the differences.

Comment: I've been doing my taxes for years, so this isn't the first couple of times. I'm just not sure why they're priced so differently.

Comment: MrChrister - curious what caused even that small difference. You recall?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - don't know.  My taxes were simple and I only entered the values off of the forms I had.  I assumed a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have used TurboTax for years with no problems. I clicked on the TaxAct link in an ad and decided to see if there was much different. Using the free version of Taxact, and inputting the exact same information, my federal taxes came out with a $1500 difference while my state taxes (NJ) came out almost identically. I rechecked my inputs twice and could find no typos in either program. While I would make out better with the TaxAct program in my wallet, I find the detailed questioning and directions in TurboTax to be superior. Somehow I am thinking that TaxAct has missed something but I can't figure out what. And the only way to actually print out your forms with TaxAct is to get the paid version, so comparing the final forms side bybside isn't a free option.

Answer (score 0):

Like most software it's about what you put in to them. We use ProSeries software which is like TurboTax but $4500 with no questions. 
 I would do your taxes on online and then have a professional do them. You then can ask any questions you may have to better understanding of what's going on. Only take copies of your documents because some unprofessional places will try to keep them.  Do this each time something big changes in your life, you have a baby, buy a house or start a business.  May cost more but could save you thousands in the long run.  I have been doing taxes professionally for 7 years.